# Save a 'search' for later email notification

Tags: php, mysql, search

I do have a portal where you search for entries. I want to implement a function to save your email for a search to let the portal send you a notification if there are more entries matching my search. The search itself does have several parameters which might change in the future.

I only see two options here, which both are not satisfying

1. Save each parameter in a column, which implies changing the table each time the search parameter change
2. Save the parameters as json encoded string, like wordpress handles it, which kind of feels like a sluggish solution (which also implies going through (and editing) each entry if the parameters itself change

My question: what is the best practise to store data like this for 'easy in the future' use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you design the table scheme, you should never have to change it. This always leads to many problems.

The goal is to save **searches**, which are composed of **parameters** and their concrete **values**. This looks like 3 tables to me:

```
searches(id, user_id, created_at, ...)
parameters(id, name, ...)
values(search_id, parameter_id, value)
```

Where `values.search_id` and `values.parameter_id` are foreign keys referencing to `searches.id` and `parameters.id` respectively.

Comment: thank you! don't know why i haven't thought of this solution :/

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean by "never have to change it"? Business change, requirements change, do you really set your tables in stone once you release your first iteration?

Comment: @ishegg No. Of course, sometimes you do have to change the database structure - as you say, requirements change. I was merely indicating that these changes are problematic and you should always try to avoid them by carefully designing the scheme from the beginning.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký right, agreed. Wouldn't it be ideal if clients weren't all up in our business asking for schema-changing requirements :). +1

Comment: @ishegg Yeah. Worst thing that can happen to a developer: Client getting an idea.

Answer (score 0):

My best advise would be to create a table dedicated to save those values. In this table, each time an user make a search, you store the value of the search input, the ID of the user, and the timestamp which belongs to the search request.

This way, you'll be able, in the future to make whatever you want. All your datas will be store in a distinct table dedicated to get statistics.

Comment: so you prefer option 1 then, a table where each parameter does have its own column with the the 'setback' of the need to edit the columns of this table each time the parameter might change?

Comment: No! you dont change the parameter each time ! you create a new entry each time ! if user 1 search for 'X', and then for 'Y', then you'll have 2 lines ! this way you can really get everything. Did you understand my path ?

Comment: ah...you mean as an allocation table with your said columns and each parameter does get its own row? well this will indeed solve the 'editing' problem

Comment: Anyway, if you want stats, you need datas. So dont focus on updating last search or stuffs like that. Just store every search from every user, and from there it's easy to retrieve the last search of an user, same way as it's easy to retrieve the user's informations, and it has the big advantage to let you a hudge amount of data, in a separate table (which means will not being parsed by MySQL to get some stuffs) unlike you want to acces your statistics.

Comment: dont be mad, although you hinted me in the right direction, Martin Heralecký's answer was way more precise and easier to understand

Comment: no problems ^^as long as it fits your needs, that's all good for me :D